# NeoVim0.9 installation cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: neovim, linux-ubuntu, system, wsl2

I was upgrading my very old NeoVim version 0.4 to 0.8 by following the docs on Github. After downloading the nvim appimage, making it executable, and extracting it using `./nvim.appimage`, I try to run `./squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim` for it to throw the following error:

```bash
-bash: ./squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I am running Ubuntu Linux WSL2

```bash
$uname -svr
Linux 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft #1237-Microsoft Sat Sep 11 14:32:00 PST 2021

$file ./squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim
./squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked,
interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=52108f8765868a43a235345926ba1a9fd5c7cc3c, with debug_info, not stripped
```

I think the problem is that nvim seems to be compiled for `GNU/Linux 3.2.0` while my WSL2 sys is `Linux 4.4.0`, but the question is how do I solve it?

If this might be any useful, when I run the same extracted nvim file with `sudo`, I get an entirely different error: `unterminated quoted string`

Comment: Is the download complete? Maybe you've got an incomplete executable because the download finished halfway e.g. due to network reasons

Comment: @Hoblovski the download was complete, my browser showed it complete, and I did all of this 2 times